# How can I create a conditional for checkout messages?

Tags: checkout

[image: checkout messages]

```
  <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
                * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?>
            </p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I need to edit the cart item messages as represented in the image above. Its rendered by the code below it. I need to remove the "order today..." message if the second item renders. I also need to change the color of the backordered phrase.

Comment: What is the class type on the output? Can you just target with CSS / JS?

Comment: Its a for each that renders the same classes. If I target with nth-child or nth of type it changes because of the "order today" removal that JS would do.  UNless I'm looking at it the wrong way. The text is in Cataloginventory/Model/Stock/Item.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to prevent these messages from being displayed to begin with. Otherwise you're just laying on complexity to avoid this.

But if you really want to know:

The cheap and dirty way (pseudocode, untested):

```
<?php
$messages = $this->getMessages();
$outputMessages = [];
foreach($messages as $message){
    if(stristr($message['text'],'backordered'){
        //find the key of the offending message
        $key = array_search($message['text'], $outputMessages);
        //remove the key we found
        unset($outputMessages[$key]);
    }
    $outputMessages[] = $message;
}
```

Don't do this in the templates, make a new method to handle for you.